# AJAX type error, data is null

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm doing data passing through AJAX all the time, but I hav'nt saw any error like that before.. It says:

```
TypeError: data is null
```

Here is my JS:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "validations/mod_validations/step_one",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: transfer_data,
        success: function (data) {

            if(data.category){
                $("#msg_error_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                    $(this).find('span').html(data.category)
                });
                ajax_1 = 1;
            } else if(data.subcategory){
                $("#msg_error_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                    $(this).find('span').html(data.subcategory)
                });
                ajax_1 = 1;
            } else if(data.mod_name){
                $("#msg_error_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                    $(this).find('span').html(data.mod_name)
                });
                ajax_1 = 1;
            } else if(data.mod_version){
                $("#msg_error_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                    $(this).find('span').html(data.mod_version)
                });
                ajax_1 = 1;
            } else if(data.success){
                ajax_1 = 0;
            }                 
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
```

Here is my transfer data:

```
var transfer_data = {
        category        :   $("#mod_add_category").val(),
        subcategory     :   $("#mod_add_subcategory").val(),
        mod_name        :   $("#mod_add_name").val(),
        mod_version     :   $("#mod_add_version").val()            
};
```

And here is my validation code (I'm using codeigniter, so there is my controller function:

```
public function step_one(){
    $user_data = array(
        "category" => $this->input->post('category'),
        "subcategory" => $this->input->post('subcategory'),
        "mod_name" => $this->input->post('mod_name'),
        "mod_version" => $this->input->post('mod_version')
    );
    $report = array();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'category', 'trim|required|callback_CheckCatForExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subcategory', 'subcategory', 'trim|required|callback_CheckSubCatForExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mod_name', 'modification name', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[50]|callback_CheckIfNameExists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mod_version', 'modification version', 'trim|required');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('CheckIfNameExists', 'exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('CheckCatForExists', 'cat not exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('CheckSubCatForExists', 'subcat not exists');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $report['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
    } else {
        $report['errors']  = array('success' => 'Passed');            
    }

    echo json_encode($report);
}
```

so where the problem could be?

Comment: What line is that err on?

Comment: My guess is step_one has a PHP error.  And is returning either the error message, or dying quietly.  Can you use Firebug to see the response, or call step_one directly from browser?

Comment: I called step_one directly from browser and got `{"errors":false}`

Comment: tymeJV, the line is `if(data.category){`

Comment: In most cases this is due to parsing errors or empty responses. You should do some tests watching the response on the console. If you use Chrome, you can do so on the Network tab of the Developer Tools (F12). If you use IE, you can do so on the Network tab also, but you have to click in "begin capture" before sending the request.

Comment: this is the problem with JS. Response from PHP is good, but JS can't receive it